# Equivalent Groups

Tags: social-networking, stata

In Stata I have this data of people who have worked together on a project. Each row is a project and there are columns person_1 to person_20, and if a name is in that column it means that person worked on that project in the row. A group can be 1 person, 2 people, ..., 20 people. I have a binary variable (yes = 1) for each possibility: Group of 1 (G1), G2, ..., G11. Then I used this code to make the groupings (using the 4 person group as an example):

```
project_group = person_1 + "/" + person_2 + "/" + person_3 + "/" + person_4 if G4 == 1
This yields: Tom/Joe/Mike/Sally
```

I have three questions:
1) Is there a more efficient way to make the groupings. For example, code that just looks across a project (a row), counts how many people are there (how many fields are not empty) and then creates a unique group name that is each person's name separated by "/". I am fine with the code I created but my dataset will change in size and more efficient code is probably best

2) How can I treat, from my example, Joe/Tom/Mike/Sally or Sally/Joe/Mike/Time as the same group. I would prefer that all of the groups, no matter the size, listed each person by alphabetical order. From my example, the list would be Joe/Mike/Sally/Tom no matter the actual permutation.

3) How do I make a group unique based on the first person (if they are  a project leader they are the first name listed). So Joe/Tom/Mike and Joe/Mike/Tom are the same Group but Tom/Joe/Mike and Mike/Tom/Joe are not.

Thanks for the help and suggestions

Comment: I reordered my solution. I think any scale-able solution here recodes your data, but this can be done in a loop to minimize typing.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged my approach to be more clear. You mentioned that you can't recode your variables, but I'm not sure if there's a way around that (I think any solution here recodes either explicitly or implicitly). Of course, you'll need to replace "4" with "20" throughout.

```
* generate some projects and members
clear
set obs 5
generate int project = _n
generate person_1 = "Tom"
generate person_2 = "Dick" if (_n >= 3)
generate person_3 = "Harry" if (_n >=5)
replace person_1 = "Jane" if inlist(_n, 2, 4)
tempfile orig
save `orig'

* reshape to long
reshape long person_, i(project) string
drop _j
drop if missing(person)
sort project person
egen id = group(person)
drop if missing(id)
reshape wide person, i(project) j(id)

* recode to allow easier group identification
forvalues i = 1/4 {
    levelsof person_`i', local(name) clean
    generate byte d_person_`i' = cond(missing(person_`i'), 0, 1)
    label define d_person_`i'_lbl 1 "`name'" 0 ""
    label values d_person_`i' d_person_`i'_lbl
}

* determine number of workers on project
egen gp_size = rowtotal(d_person_*)

* unique id for each group composition
generate int id = 0
forvalues i = 1/4 {
    local two_i = 2^(`i' - 1)
    replace id = id + d_person_`i' * `two_i'
}

* group members
generate str mbrs = ""
forvalues i = 1/4 {
    local name: label d_person_`i'_lbl 1
    replace mbrs = mbrs + "/" + "`name'" if (d_person_`i' == 1)
}   

* there's always a leading "/" to remove with this approach
replace m = substr(m, 2, .)

* merge back your orig data
merge 1:1 project using `orig', nogenerate replace update
```

This yields:

```
. list

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | project   person_1   person_2   person_3   person_4   d_pers~1   d_pers~2   d_pers~3   d_pers~4   gp_size   id             mbrs |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1        Tom                              Tom                                         Tom         1    8              Tom |
  2. |       2       Jane                  Jane                                        Jane                    1    4             Jane |
  3. |       3        Tom       Dick                   Tom       Dick                              Tom         2    9         Dick/Tom |
  4. |       4       Jane       Dick       Jane                  Dick                  Jane                    2    5        Dick/Jane |
  5. |       5        Tom       Dick      Harry        Tom       Dick      Harry                   Tom         3   11   Dick/Harry/Tom |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't see how this code addresses the permutations and alphabetic ordering. Besides, my understanding is that the OP's data structure is different: `person_1` will always be non-empty, `person_2` will be non-empty for projects with 2+ people who worked on it, etc.

Comment: @richardh Thanks for the code, however, StasK is correct, this does not address my main questions in (2) and (3), and my data is structured in a way that person_1 is always non-empty and if there is a name in person_4 that means it is a 4 person project. Any ideas on addressing (2) and (3) would be helpful.

Comment: I wasn't sure how your data were coded, so I went with how I would code it. With the coding that @StasK describes you will have a hard time addressing (2) and (3). I think your best best is to recode your data.

Comment: @Stask do you have any thoughts? I cannot change the way my data are coded.

Comment: I would do this in Mata, so as to be able to sort across the row (to produce a unique group label for your tasks (1) and (2); the task (3) is obviously easily addressed, as in Fr's answer.). Developing a robust solution would take me some time, and I have work priorities right now. You can ask at statalist, in the mean time.

Comment: Is there something the above solution doesn't do? It seems this achieves all three points.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there a more efficient way to make the groupings.

I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with your current arrangement, which seems clean and easily readable.

> 2) How can I treat, from my example, Joe/Tom/Mike/Sally or Sally/Joe/Mike/Time as the same group.

I'll assume you meant Tom and not Time in your last string.

```
egen team_size = anycount(person_1-person_20), v(1)
gen team_leader = .
if team_size > 0 replace team_leader = person_1
gen team_structure = 0
replace team_structure = team_structure + regexm(project_group,"Joe")
replace team_structure = team_structure + regexm(project_group,"Tom")*10
replace team_structure = team_structure + regexm(project_group,"Mike")*100
replace team_structure = team_structure + regexm(project_group,"Sally")*1000
```

The `team_structure` is a $k$-length binary that codes for the team membership of $k$ members irrespective of the order in which they might show in the `project_group` string. This is code-expensive if you have a lot of members, but pretty easy to create.

> 3) How do I make a group unique based on the first person (if they are a project leader they are the first name listed). So Joe/Tom/Mike and Joe/Mike/Tom are the same Group but Tom/Joe/Mike and Mike/Tom/Joe are not.

Trivial suggestion: add a factor to each possible member (`encode`), and assign it to the decimal of the `team_structure` variable created above. Example: 1011.1 is the group Joe/Mike/Sally led by Joe, 1011.4 is the same group led by Sally, and so on.